# Android isShrinkResources removed by gradle plugin 7.0.0-alpha15. How to shrink resources?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Latest Android gradle plugin 7.0.0-alpha15 removed the option `isShrinkResources` in `BuildType`.
Does `isMinifyEnabled` now superseeds it, or is there a new way to ensure the resources will be shrinked when building the app?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187082355

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Google, the missing isShrinkResources issue is fixed in an upcoming AGP 7.0-beta1
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186806256